# AR FOUNDATION RAYCASTING: using RayCast to determine where to place the Z position

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, arkit, arcore

I am developing a simple AR foundation app to draw small spheres on the space once you touch the screen. The problem am having the objects are drawn but they are not staying on the real-world object once I move my camera. This is due to my Z position is hardcoded to 8 and it becomes very difficult for the drawn AR object to remain on the real object especially when the camera is moved.

Do you have the solution for that by the use of AR foundation Raycasting?

If so, can you share a sample of it that I can replace here

Here is my Unity C# code.

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;
using agora_gaming_rtc;

public class RemoteDrawer : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    IRtcEngine rtcEngine;

    Camera arCam;     // the AR Camera
    Camera renderCam; // the Renderer Camera, space of 3D objects
    Camera viewCam; // the viewer of the projected quad, acting camera since AR Camera projects into a RenderTexture

    [SerializeField] Transform referenceObject = null;

    [SerializeField] GameObject DrawPrefab = null;

    public float DotScale = 0.15f;

    private GameObject anchorGO;
    private Color DrawColor = Color.black;

    void Start()
    {
        rtcEngine = IRtcEngine.QueryEngine();
        if (rtcEngine != null)
        {
            rtcEngine.OnStreamMessage += HandleStreamMessage;
        }

        CamStart();
    }


    /// <summary>
    ///    The delegate function to handle message sent from Audience side
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="userId"></param>
    /// <param name="streamId"></param>
    /// <param name="data"></param>
    /// <param name="length"></param>
    void HandleStreamMessage(uint userId, int streamId, string data, int length)
    {
        if (data.Contains("color"))
        {
            StartCoroutine(CoProcessDrawingData(data));
        }
        else if (data.Contains("clear"))
        {
            Destroy(anchorGO);
        }


        Debug.LogWarning("Main Camera pos = " + Camera.main.transform.position);
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///  Do the drawing async
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="data"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    IEnumerator CoProcessDrawingData(string data)
    {
        try
        {
            DrawmarkModel dm = JsonUtility.FromJson<DrawmarkModel>(data);
            DrawColor = dm.color;
            foreach (Vector2 pos in dm.points)
            {
                DrawDot(pos);
            }
        }
        catch (System.Exception e)
        {
            Debug.LogError(e);
        }
        yield return null;
    }


    int dotCount = 0;
    /// <summary>
    ///   
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="pos">Screen Position</param>
    void DrawDot(Vector2 pos)
    {
        if (anchorGO == null)
        {
            anchorGO = new GameObject();
            anchorGO.transform.SetParent(referenceObject.transform.parent);
            anchorGO.transform.position = Vector3.zero;
            anchorGO.transform.localScale = Vector3.one;
            anchorGO.name = "DrawAnchor";
        }


        // DeNormalize the position and adjust to passed camera
        Vector3 location = DeNormalizedPosition(pos, renderCam);


        GameObject go = GameObject.Instantiate(DrawPrefab, location, Quaternion.identity);
        go.transform.SetParent(anchorGO.transform);
        go.transform.localScale = DotScale * Vector3.one;
        go.layer = (int)CameraLayer.IGNORE_RAYCAST;
        go.name = "dot " + dotCount;
        dotCount++;
        Debug.LogFormat("{0} pos:{1} => : {2} ", go.name, pos, location);
        Renderer renderer = go.GetComponent<Renderer>();
        if (renderer != null)
        {
            Material mat = renderer.material;
            if (mat != null)
            {
                mat.color = DrawColor;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///    Provide a ViewPort Position (0,0) = bottom left and (1,1) top right
    /// return world position for the current camera
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="vector2"></param>
    /// <param name="camera"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    Vector3 DeNormalizedPosition(Vector2 vector2, Camera camera)
    {

        Vector3 pos = new Vector3(vector2.x, vector2.y);

        pos = camera.ViewportToScreenPoint(pos);

        // Consider using the referenceObject for position calculation
        // Vector3 deltaPos = camera.transform.position - referenceObject.position;

        pos = new Vector3(pos.x, pos.y, 8);

        return camera.ScreenToWorldPoint(pos);
    }

    // Use this for initialization
    void CamStart()
    {
        renderCam = GameObject.Find("RenderCamera").GetComponent<Camera>();
        arCam = GameObject.Find("AR Camera").GetComponent<Camera>();
        viewCam = GameObject.Find("ViewCamera").GetComponent<Camera>();
    }
}
```

This is the line where am stacked. How can I use AR Foundation Raycasting to determine Z position? For now I have hardcoded.

```
pos = new Vector3(pos.x, pos.y, 8);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using ARFoundation and you just want to place an object on a surface then use `ARRaycastManager`.

Then in your code just make a raycast

```
if (raycastManager.Raycast(position, hitResults))
    {
        //hitResults[0].pose.position is the position you are looking for
    }
```

I'm not sure why you made such a complicated code, but just take a look at `RaycastManager`.

Comment: But for this case, am placing the object on the space.

Comment: Thanks for the help. The reason i have written that much is because once the users touches the screen, the user can be able to draw on the screen. The points where the user touches, the small Game Object sphere are instantiated. Hence, the game object is instantiated on the "Air space" rather than the surface space. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I switched my camera from orthographic to perspective(ArCamera Vuforia) and started having trouble getting the point of the world.

When I put the Z of the camera position, I get the point very well.

```
Vector3 mousePosition = new Vector3 (Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, 18.9f);
Vector3 objPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (mousePosition);
```

[Camera position Z](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VLri6.png)